# How To Update Laravel hasMany Relationship Models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I've been trying to wrap my head on figuring out how to update my hasMany relationship model. I can easily create new relationships but when I try to update my relationship model it does not work? Does laravel push() method still work? Can anyone help please? For example I want to update my Taxonomy Table thats related to my Products table within my Controller. I have a code snippet below::

**Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_category', 'product_subcategory', 'product_name', 
        'product_price', 'product_id', 'product_description', 'product_image'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function addTaxonomiesToProduct()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Taxonomies', 'product_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

**Taxonomies.php**

```
class Taxonomies extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['product_category', 'product_subcategory'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id'; // or null

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**EditProductController.php**

```
class EditProductController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {

          $product_size = array();
          foreach ($request->product_size as $key => $value) 
           {
              array_push($product_size,$value);

           }
        $product->update([
            'product_name'        => $request->product_name,
            'product_price'       => $request->product_price,
            'product_description' => $request->product_description,
            'product_size'        => serialize($product_size),
            'product_image'       => $product_image_path,
        ]);

        /**
         * Go the products table,
         * Get the product based off its product_id,
         * and then update this products taxonomy
         **/
        $taxonomies = Product::find($product->product_id);
        $taxonomies->addTaxonomiesToProduct->product_subcategory = "Mens Shoes";

        $taxonomies->push();
    }
}
```

****Update Issued Solved****
By changing hasMany() to hasOne() within my Products table, my taxonomies table updated correctly.

Comment: @ Ross Wilson, thanks so much for indenting that for me!!!!

Comment: Is a product meant to have one `Taxonomies` or can it have more?

Comment: @ Ross Wilson, a product can have multiple taxonomies

Comment: Ok, so how do you know which `Taxonomies` you want to edit? Or do you want to update all of them?

Comment: @ Ross Wilson, Well I'm using the product_id for the Parent Table (Product), and within my Taxonomies Table I also have a product_id. And with this unique product_id I want to edit the matching taxonomie column (product_category)

Comment: Yes, but you've just said one `Product` could have multiple `Taxonomies` so how do you know which of the (potentially) multiple `Taxonomies` with that `product_id` you want to edit?

Comment: @ Ross Wilson, Actually a product can have one Taxonomie not many, I may need to change this to reflect my taxonomies table.

Comment: Ross Wilson, I got it to work!! thanks for gudiding me in the right direction. By changing my hasMany to hasOne within my Products Table, it updated correctly. So lets say I had many Taxonomies instead of one, I would still run into the same issue correct?

Comment: Yes, if you try and update it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't fully understand the way Laravel Eloquent relationships work. First off, you need to define the relationship in *both* models.. Your Taxonomy model has this, but your Product model should have: 

    `public function taxonomies() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Taxonomies', 'product_id', 'product_id');
    }`

Then to update a Product's taxonomies, you'd have something like...Uh, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, especially with the way you chained the `product_subcategory`, so I can't rightly say, but do see [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)

Comment: Just an FYI but you don't actually need to define the relationship in both models :)

Comment: If you're never calling the inverse (Product::with('taxonomies') in this case)  you don't need to define it.

Comment: It's all related to the model you are actually using. When you define a relationship in one model you're giving it all the information it needs i.e. what the relationship is to that model, what class to to poplate the information with (and also to get the table name) and what keys it should use for the query. You only need to define the inverse when you going to be using the other class to load the relationship.